# Is possible to discard outer brackets in regex and consider inner bracket inside?

Tags: regular-expression, pcregrep, pcre

I have many patterns with bracket enclosure,
I made a regular expression where is not considering brackets and just only
what is inside/between them, but exists a problem when the text within brackets
contain [] brackets too.

Thanks!

Regex: `(?<inside_value>(?<=\[).*?\[?(?=\]))`

For example,

```
A)   [ClusterReceiver[99]            ]
B)   [first-second-third-8050-exec-a       ]
```

From above, B) is working perfectly, but A) not

### What is being returned for every case (without quotes):

```
B) "first-second-third-8050-exec-a "
A) "ClusterReceiver[99"
```

### What is desired?

```
B) "first-second-third-8050-exec-a "
A) "ClusterReceiver[99]"
```

The problem is when exist `[ ]` bracket enclosure within outer `[ ]` enclosure.

The worst case is when exists that problem like A),
can you help me by giving a suggestion how to accept at least 1 bracket, in order to have A) as desired "ClusterReceiver[99]" ?

Comment: not with normal regular expressions, they can't count. Or, rather, you could do that manually for one level of brackets (e.g. `\[[^[]*\] | \[ [^[]* \[ [^[]*\] \] [^[]* \]` with Perl's `/x`. Or something like that anyway.) but if you want to support nesting to an arbitrary level, that's harder. Perl regexes do contain features that allow you to implement full parsers with them, but that's a bit of a change from plain regexes.

Answer (score 0):

Using `pcregrep`

```
$ pcregrep -o1 -o2 '([^[]*)\[([^]]*[[:alnum:]]][^]]*).*' input_file
A)   ClusterReceiver[99]
B)   first-second-third-8050-exec-a
```